# Unable to invite internal users in apple TestFlight

Tags: testflight

I have no experience in publishing apps on the App Store. I have created an app from Xcode 6, archived it, validate it and submitted to iTunes Connect. While is pending for being reviewed I decided to try the new apple TestFlight functionality.

Following the tutorial video (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/TestFlight-v09-iTC-Export-sw.mov) I have performed these steps:

- I have added another apple ID that I own under the User & Role section giving him a Technical role
- I have accepted the iTunes Connect email invitation for that user
- I have selected my app, then my build and enabled it for TestFlight
- I went under the Internal Testers section and invited the user

Still the status for the user is not being displayed as invited and I didn't received any email invitation to test the build.

[image: The status didn't change to Invited]

As you can see I also tried to invite my own apple id account, the status changed to invited but I didn't received any email...

In addition refreshing the page brings me back to no invitation at all for the new user:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I fear I am missing a step during the build submission or maybe that since the app is reviewing for the app store I cannot invite beta testers...

I have also tried to toggle again the testflight build toggle (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26579651/2701348) but nothing changed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem with inviting an internal tester is that you cannot have an internal and external tester with the same apple ID.

Although deleted and recreated the user in user roles I still had the same problem. When I removed the duplicate email from External Testers and went back to Internal Testers, the invite was sent.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Apple should warn about this little detail in the TestFlight's Export Test Users manual. Thank you!

Comment: @Niko Zarzani, consider accepting this as an answer.

Comment: I accepted it, I don't know if my issue was really due to that fact but I hope this helps :)

Comment: I had this; I deleted the tester from the external tester, then had to reselect the checkbox for it in internal. But then when I went back to external testers the apple ID was back there!  iTunes Connect is the worst! (So I deleted the user entirely and re-added them)

Comment: Actually another user i had this problem with, I deleted their account entirely but when they re-enroll the apple ID shows up in both external and internal again!

Comment: @shim: When I delete the internal testers I go to Users and Roles and delete them completely. I think that External testers are just the email in the 'External Testers' list to be deleted and that's all. When I do this I have no issues and I cannot reproduce the issue you came across. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the issue. To make the invitations work again you must:

- Under Internal Testers and Users and Roles: delete the users you are not able to invite
- Under Users and Roles invite them again to join iTunes Connect
- Enable them as testers
- Go to your app build and invite them again as internal testers

Hope this might be useful.